# Re-producing Microsoft PowerShell repo test project to install and Running AZ PowerShell SDK in C# .net6

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to run install and run Azure PowerShell modules in C# and invoke the script.

Installing Azure PowerShell modules called from C# **.net6.0 is doable**. This is from the Microsoft PowerShell team:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/blob/master/test/perf/benchmarks/BenchmarksV3RemoteRepo.cs

So I created a simple C# code to reproduce it.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using Microsoft.PowerShell;

// Setting up the PowerShell runspace
var defaultSS = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
defaultSS.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
var pwsh = PowerShell.Create(defaultSS);

// Import the PSGet version we want to test
pwsh.AddScript(@"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Import-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 3.0.14 -Force");
var result = pwsh.Invoke();
foreach (var outputItem in result) Debug.WriteLine(outputItem);

pwsh.Commands.Clear();
pwsh.AddScript("Install-PSResource -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -TrustRepository -Reinstall");
var results = pwsh.Invoke();

foreach (var outputItem in results) Debug.WriteLine(outputItem);
```

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.CoreCLR.Eventing" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Native" Version="7.3.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Security" Version="7.2.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.7"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Errors:

```
The specified module 'PowerShellGet' with version '3.0.14' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
The term 'Install-PSResource' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

To view the error buffer inspect the `powershell.ErrorBuffer.Result` value

[image]

Comment: Is powershell script running from powershell cmd prompt in your environment?

Comment: When you install a cmdlet it must be in the PSModulePath environmental variable.  Use cmd.exe >Set will show the variable.  You either need to add a new path to PSModulePath or load the cmdlet into an existing path.  See following for more help : https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/01/import-module-specified-module-not-loaded-because-no-valid-module-file-found-in-any-module-directory.html.  When you install a new version it must be before an older version in the path otherwise the older version will execute.

Comment: This Command worked for me try to use Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 3.0.14-beta14 -AllowPrerelease -Force .

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and I have faced similar error as below:

[image]

Then I have used the below command:

```
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 3.0.14-beta14 -AllowPrerelease -Force
```

By using the above command my error got resolved.